# optional parameter in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to make few paramters optional using regular expression

currently my url is

> http://[ipaddress]/StoreData/10/20/30/40/50

as there are 5 numbered parameters , now sometimes  i want 4 or sometime 5

> i.e.
>   http://[ipaddress]/StoreData/10/20/30/40

should be acceptable

here is my regular expression

```
(?P<dataone>([0-9])+)/(?P<datatwo>([0-9])+)/(?P<datathree>([0-9])+)/(?P<datafour>([0-9])+)/(?P<datafive>([0-9])+)/
```

Comment: Your example is invalid, as your regular expression requires a `/` at the end but the example strings don't have one.

Comment: well if i don't use slash then also it is working

Comment: Ah, true. This is because the regexp isn't rooted at the end with `$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?` modifier makes a part of a regular expression optional:

```
(?P<dataone>([0-9])+)/(?P<datatwo>([0-9])+)/(?P<datathree>([0-9])+)/(?P<datafour>([0-9])+)/((?P<datafive>([0-9])+)/)?
```

Note the `(...)?` around the "datafive" subpattern.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was asking about the slashes in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
StoreData/(?P<dataone>([0-9])*)/(?P<datatwo>([0-9])*)/(?P<datathree>([0-9])*)/(?P<datafour>([0-9])*)/?(?P<datafive>([0-9])*)/?$
```

will be the required regex. Escape the regex, if required.

to Answer Petri Lehtinen and  Lasse V. Karlsen, it will handle the trailing backslash also.